# What does "cd !$" mean in bash, and what other substitutions like these can I use?

Tags: bash, shell

I've seen somebody do:

```
cp . yy/
cd !$
```

the last line translated to:

```
cd yy/
```

so I think `!$` means "the last argument from previous line".

Am I right?

Are there any other substitution of this kind?

Where can I find the documentation for them?

Comment: Thanks!  Now that I see that the question was pretty basic, and so you answered it in the comments and three of you already voted for closing it, what's the proper thing to do?  Should I delete it or just leave it here unanswered?

Comment: It will probably get migrated to super user, so I would leave it because it may be useful to future bash'ers on SU.  I also threw in an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`!$` is the last *word* of the last command.

More:

`!!` - Last command
`!foo` - Run most recent command starting with `foo` (ex. `!ps`, `!mysqladmin`)
`!foo:p` - Print command that `!foo` would run, and add it as the latest to command history
`!$` - Last 'word' of last command (`/path/to/file` in the command `ls -lAFh /path/to/file`, `-uroot` in `mysql -uroot`)
`!$:p` - Print word that `!$` would substitute
`!*` - All but first word of last command (`-lAFh /path/to/file` in the command `ls -lAFh /path/to/file`, `-uroot` in `mysql -uroot`)
`!*:p` - Print words that !* would substitute

`^foo^bar` - Replace `foo` in last command with `bar`, print the result, then run. (`mysqladmni -uroot`, run `^ni^in`, results in `mysqladmin -uroot`)

`{a,b,c}` passes words to the command, substituting `a`, `b`, and `c` sequentially (`cp file{,.bk}` runs `cp file file.bk`)

<kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd> - Jump to the start of the line
<kbd>Ctrl + b</kbd> - Move back a char
<kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> - Terminate the command
<kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> - Delete from under the cursor
<kbd>Ctrl + e</kbd> - Jump to the end of the line
<kbd>Ctrl + f</kbd> - Move forward a char
<kbd>Ctrl + k</kbd> - Delete to EOL
<kbd>Ctrl + l</kbd> - Clear the screen
<kbd>Ctrl + r</kbd> - Search the history backwards
<kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> - Search the history backwards with multi occurrence
<kbd>Ctrl + t</kbd> - Transpose the current char with the previous
<kbd>Ctrl + u</kbd> - Delete backward from cursor
<kbd>Ctrl + w</kbd> - Delete backward a word
<kbd>Ctrl + xx</kbd> - Move between EOL and current cursor position
<kbd>Ctrl + x @</kbd> - Show possible hostname completions
<kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> - Suspend/ Stop the command
<kbd>Ctrl + x;</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + e</kbd> - Edit line into your favorite editor

<kbd>Alt + <</kbd> - Move to the first line in the history
<kbd>Alt + ></kbd> - Move to the last line in the history
<kbd>Alt + ?</kbd> - Show current completion list
<kbd>Alt + *</kbd> - Insert all possible completions
<kbd>Alt + /</kbd> - Attempt to complete filename
<kbd>Alt + .</kbd> - Yank last argument to previous command
<kbd>Alt + b</kbd> - Move backward
<kbd>Alt + c</kbd> - Capitalize the word
<kbd>Alt + d</kbd> - Delete word
<kbd>Alt + f</kbd> - Move forward
<kbd>Alt + l</kbd> - Make word lowercase
<kbd>Alt + n</kbd> - Search the history forwards non-incremental
<kbd>Alt + p</kbd> - Search the history backwards non-incremental
<kbd>Alt + r</kbd> - Recall command
<kbd>Alt + t</kbd> - Transpose the current word with the previous
<kbd>Alt + u</kbd> - Make word uppercase
<kbd>Alt + back-space</kbd> - Delete backward from cursor

From http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/bash/.

Also, lots of good stuff here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html
and here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html.